# Will StackOverflow ever be sold to a major company? If so, when?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, google

It's already old news that Google bought [vark.com](http://www.vark.com), which have a similar purpose but is nothing like this. Yet, thanks to that, maybe it's unlikely they'd have any interest.

So maybe some other have an interest? It's probably popping out into many companies eyes by now and for some time.

Well, what do you think? Got any inside views? Just speculating?

I think if it doesn't sell within 2 years, it could be big enough on its own.

Comment: A legitimate concern.  A company's "suck factor" almost always increases with its size and/or change of ownership.  Sometimes it even outpaces it by orders of magnitude.  Let's hope SO doesn't go that route.

Comment: *...it could be big enough on its own.* - Big enough for what? Is this an actual question or just asking for a psychic reading?

Comment: When? Not 6 to 8 weeks I hope...

Comment: Just sayin': http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20668/new-close-reason-question-asks-to-predict-the-future

Comment: Vote to close: "useless speculation"

Comment: it was just bought https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/

Comment: @scunliffe thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They seem to want to continue operating on their own:

[**Raising money for StackOverflow**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/02/14.html)

Related MSO discussion:

- [Possible negative effects of VC funding for StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39545/possible-negative-effects-of-vc-funding-for-stackoverflow)
- [Possible positive effects of VC funding for StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39646/possible-positive-effects-of-vc-funding-for-stackoverflow)
- [Would you take a share in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39539/would-you-take-a-share-in-stack-overflow)
- [What is the profitability and future business outlook of the StackOverflow family of sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6140/what-is-the-profitability-and-future-business-outlook-of-the-stackoverflow-family)

Comment: and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-000004/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will be, but if it is... it will happen in six to eight weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff and Joel talk about seeking venture capital near the beginning of [Podcast #85](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/podcast-85/).  From that conversation, it sounds like they really want to keep control of SO.  I don't think they're going to sell it any time soon.